# Migrate a project from Mantis to Redmine?

Tags: redmine, data-migration, mantis

The [official Redmine documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineMigrate) teaches how to migrate the full Mantis database, including all users, projects and issues. Is there a way to do it on a per-project basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything on the subject in the open-source community.

There is a commercial tool, however. It's called Task Adapter. We have successfully used it to import a certain project from Mantis into Redmine.

Comment: Vladimir, can you please elaborate on how exactly you used Task Adapter to migrate the data? Did you have any problems?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a free program for migrating tasks from mantis to redmine. You can filter mantis issues by project and export it into XML. Download zip archive from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Qycu9v6OK5Z2RDWVpOSVNBRmM/view?usp=sharing). Unzip it in any folder and run mantis_redmine.exe. Next follow user guide http://ramilnotes.blogspot.ru/2016/09/importissuesfrommantistoredmine.html. This program uses XML export from mantis to import issues to redmine. I've approved it on redmine 3.3.0.